# RFC error message "The current application triggered a termination with a short dump"

Tags: c#, .net, saprfc

SAP is backend and .Net is frontend of my application. I am getting an exception that says "the current application triggered a termination with a short dump" while executing a RFC call. I used SAP.Net connector for building dll's.

```
GetConnection objCon = new GetConnection();
Utilities objUtil = new Utilities();
ZZZZ_Z.ZZZZ_Z_MOVEMENT objSave = new ZZZZ_Z.ZZZZ_Z__MOVEMENT();
ZZZZ_Z.ZST_MESSAGETable objMessageTable = new ZZZZ_Z.ZST_MESSAGETable();
ZZZZ_Z.ZST_MESSAGE1Table objMsgTableNew = new ZZZZ_Z.ZST_MESSAGE1Table();
objSave.Connection = objCon.setConnection();
objSave.ZZZZ__Movement(ID,names, out EX_FLAG, out RETMSG, ref objMessageTable, ref objMsgTableNew);
DataTable MESSAGE_TABLE = new DataTable();
MESSAGE_TABLE = objMsgTableNew.ToADODataTable();
objSave.Connection.Close();
return objMessageTable.ToADODataTable();
```

What is the cause of this error message and how can I find out more about the problem?

Comment: Post your RFC call?  RFC is a remote function that is created in SAP, .net calls this RFC.  You can explicitly call this RFC right from within SAP using I think SE80 (or the abap editor).

Comment: That's a SAP error message. First google result for the message [(link here)](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscn.sap.com%2Fmessage%2F8290651&ei=bByRUIXfIY_14QSl6YDIBw&usg=AFQjCNEvKZNYN2ZR2BOM97nHeYumxdneWA&sig2=00zXR7m7FEV5HP5ehLknEg) looks like some helpful hints are provided there.

Comment: Thanks alex for link.please let me know more about this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic error message that only says "Something went wrong, but I can't tell you what, at least not through the current communication channel. However, I left a short dump to examine." To do so, use transaction `ST22` in the backend system. This can be anything - a temporary issue, a programming error, data inconsistencies, you name it - anything that caused the program to bail out completely.